# How to show laravel.log content

Tags: laravel, logging

How can i get all text and sentences (content) from laravel.log file?

this below code is not working for me :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$logs = fopen("storage\logs\laravel.log", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($logs, filesize("laravel.log"));
fclose($logs);

return response()->json($logs);
```

and my error :

```
fopen(storage/logs/laravel.log): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer This is a popular package to view Laravel logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access using

```
$logPath = storage_path().'/logs/laravel.log';
$logs = fopen($logPath , "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

And make sure *laravel.log* exists.

Comment: i complete your answer with :

$logPath = storage_path() . '/logs/laravel.log';
$logs = fopen($logPath, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$data = stream_get_contents($logs);

return response()->json($data);

thanks bro